# How to restart the shell in script?

Tags: bash, shell, pyenv

I have a script that installs the pyenv package. Installing it requires adding environment variables, then restarting the shell.

```
apt install -y make build-essential libssl-dev zlib1g-dev \
> libbz2-dev libreadline-dev libsqlite3-dev wget curl llvm libncurses5-dev\
> libncursesw5-dev xz-utils tk-dev libffi-dev liblzma-dev python-openssl\
> git

git clone https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv.git ~/.pyenv

echo 'export PYENV_ROOT="$HOME/.pyenv"' >> ~/.bashrc
echo 'export PATH="$PYENV_ROOT/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.bashrc
echo -e 'if command -v pyenv 1>/dev/null 2>&1; then\n eval "$(pyenv init -)"\nfi' >> ~/.bashrc
```

for example after PATH:

```
exec $SHELL <<EOF1
```

How can I restart the shell so that the rest of the script continues to run?

Answer (score 2):

Think twice before having a script updating your .bashrc. In particular if you are not the only user of this script, never modify .bashrc automatically. You don't know what's in it, and how the user of your script has carefully handcrafted his .bashrc.

Instead write the settings to a separate file and request the user to source this file from inside his .bashrc (or wherever he wants to do it; perhaps he will prefer .bash_profile for this?). Therefore you do something like

```
echo 'export PYENV_ROOT="$HOME/.pyenv"' > ~/.pyenv_settings
echo 'export PATH="$PYENV_ROOT/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.pyenv_settings
source ~/.pyenv_settings
```

which also ensures that the settings are now performed inside your script.

Comment: Ok thanks, its ok. But.. I have source ~ / .pyenv settings added in the script

but then I have to manually type source ~ / .pyenv_settings into the console

for the pyenv command to work.

Comment: Of course - but you only asked how to change it so that _the rest of the script continues to run_. If you want the script to also change the environment in the calling process, you must not run that script as a child process. But this is a general principle, when running programs which fiddle with the environment, and not related to setting up the Python environment.

Comment: Then how can I run the script not as a child process?

Comment: By sourcing it!  That's the whole point, why we need a `source` statement. But it requires of course that the script is written in the same language as your current shell. Hence, if your script is bash, your interactive shell must also be bash.